# Tensor product $G\times K_n$

Tags: hamiltonian-path

Let $G$ be a Hamiltonian graph and $K_n$ the complete graph on $n$ vertices. Are there results about that the graph $G\times K_n$ is Hamiltonian or not? Thanks.

Comment: Remind me ... a graph is Hamiltonian if it has a Hamiltonian path or cycle. If $n$ is even then it is easy. But maybe you could tell us what you know so far ?

Comment: Yes, I consider a graph Hamiltonian if it has a Hamiltonian cycle. About Hamintonicity of a tensor product I have found this paper and it is only that I know about: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82211350.pdf. Actually, I'm only interested in the case when n is a prime number.

Comment: In that paper, did you notice Lemma 2 on page 254? It would seem to cover everything you are interested in except for the case $n = 2$, which shouldn't be hard to figure out.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, thanks, I was so stupid.

Comment: Don't be too hard on yourself - it's easy to miss the forest for all the trees. I said the $n=2$ case should be simple, but it seems to be more complicated than I expected. But the rest of the paper should allow you to answer it as well.